# Joomla 1.5 with JCE editor 154 - IE9 issues

Tags: internet-explorer-9, joomla1.5

We have been using Joomla 1.5 with JCE editor 154 for a few years with no problems in any browser. Some of our users now have  windows 7 and Ie9, and they cannot save, and a few other commands are not working.

Comment: Did you try to use the Debugging Script with the Developer Tools? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx)
Did you get any JS errors?